# How to identify whether the react native app is downloaded from Huawei App Gallery or Google Play Store?

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services

I created a react native application which contains in-app-purchase.

in-app purchase - [react-native-iap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap)

I published my app into google play store, ios app store and It is working fine at google play store and ios app store.
I want to publish my app in Huawei app gallery.

[react-native-iap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap) does not support Huawei and I had to implement hms in-app purchase. But after that I am facing this problem.

There are two kind of Huawei mobile phones in market now.

1. Huawei mobile phones that supports both [gms](https://www.android.com/gms/) and [hms](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/).
2. Huawei mobile phones that supports only [hms](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/).

**Huawei mobile phones that supports both [gms](https://www.android.com/gms/) and [hms](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/)**

In these user can download the app from Huawei app gallery or Google play store. How should I differentiate whether the app is download from Huawei app gallery or Google play store ?

Because based on this information I need to do the purchase (whether I use hms purchase or gms purchase)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName(String pack)`. This is an native method provided by Android for your information.

[image]

This method returns the package name of the software on which the application is installed. This method can be used to determine the market where the application was downloaded.

Comment: Thank you. I will try.